# How to use čćšž in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want something like this

```
def view(request):
    var="Ra"
    string = var+"č"
    return HttpResponse(string)
```

How I can do it in django ? I always get 
SyntaxError at /

Non-ASCII character '\xc4' in ...

EDITED :

Thanks a lot for help, 
but this isn't solved all my problems , now I'm trying to write "Č" to PDF file

```
def pdf_view(request):
# Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'


# Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
p = canvas.Canvas(response)
p.drawString(300, 800, "RA"+u"Č"+"UN BROJ 100-1-1")

p.showPage()

p.save()

return response
```

I can't get Č in pdf , I'm using from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas , to create PDF

Comment: You can try this `var=u"Ra"` `string = var+u"č"` doing so you will convert your string to unicode and might avoid such problems. So by adding `u` before string you force Python to save it as unicode instead of ASCII

Comment: Please specify if you're using Python 2 or 3, the answer won't be the same :)

Comment: I tried already  , but still get same error SyntaxError at /

Non-ASCII character '\xc4' in file views.py on line 17, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details (views.py, line 17)

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Django trying to convert non-ASCII character using ASCII table and of course it ends up with error.
To avoid this you can save strings as unicode as follows

```
var=u"Ra"
string = var + u"č"
return HttpResponse(string)
```

To use this you have to declare encoding on top of your views.py like this

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Actually you have to declare encoding in each .py file where you are using utf-8 or any other coding instead of default ASCII.
That applies only for Python 2.x because in 3.x stuff saved in utf-8 by default

Comment: It works , but mow ..  I'm trying  to write that charcter to  PDF file using reportlab

Comment: def pdf_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

 
    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(300, 800, "RA"+u"Č"+"UN BROJ 154-1-1")

    p.showPage()

    p.save()

    return response

Comment: All the literal strings should be unicode, not just the one with the Č.

Comment: p.drawString(300, 800, u"RAČUN BROJ 154-1-1") , still not working :( , you can check on www.mojbutik.webfactional.com/pdf_view , it is view  pdf_view that I added in above

Comment: Guess you should go and read some docs on this question. Because it will be hard time coding if you do not understand such basic concepts.

Comment: probably problem is in PDF font , I'm usaing Helvetica , maybe it don't supports čćšđž

Comment: Yes, I did it,  I need to change Helvetica to Vera font

Comment: Congrats!:) Anyway while things did not go far you can consider using Python 3.x because encoding there is utf-8 by default.